# ArcGIS 10.1 Upgrade Geodatabase check version?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, file-geodatabase

I am trying to check the version of a file geodatabase before upgrading to 10.1, I have a list of file geodatabases and some of them are already in 10.1. Can anyone suggest me how to update only those with version less than 10.1?

I am using python script to do this:

```
arcpy.UpgradeGDB_management(r"C:\Test\Base.gdb", "PREREQUISITE_CHECK", "UPGRADE")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code would work for you.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\93_data\93"
workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "FileGDB")

for workspace in workspaces:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(workspace)
    if desc.release != '3,0,0':
        arcpy.UpgradeGDB_management(workspace, "PREREQUISITE_CHECK", "UPGRADE")
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, when I run this it is giving me this error: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.\nFailed to execute

Comment: @Gbh I ran the code above at ArcGIS 10.2, except for the UpgradeGDB step because I wanted to not change them, and it worked fine - try `print desc.release` after setting `desc` to the Describe object and see if it works that far.

Comment: @PolyGeo my process fails at the UpgradeGDB..I'm clueless why it does that I'm giving in the correct parameters

Comment: @Gbh I think you should Accept this as the Answer to your original Question and then ask a new one with a title like "What causes Upgrade Geodatabase to throw ERROR 999999?".  That new question should be reproducible from the tool dialog, and if not, then use the Geoprocessing | Results window to Copy As Python Snippet.