# Why does ArcGIS Upgrade Geodatabase tool throw ERROR 999999: Error executing function?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, file-geodatabase, error-999999

I am using  ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop to upgrade File Geodatabases using a Python script that runs fine until the step where it runs the [Upgrade Geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000q7000000) tool. The error is:

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function.\nFailed to execute

The error can also be seen when the [Upgrade Geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000q7000000) tool is run manually so I have not re-included the code which can be found in an [earlier question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77249/arcgis-10-1-upgrade-geodatabase-check-version) which led to this one.

Does anyone know what would cause this error?

Comment: What happens when you use the Upgrade Geodatabase tool to perform the upgrade on this file geodatabase (i.e. the first one in your listed workspaces) outside of ArcPy?  If that works use the Geoprocessing | Results window to Copy As Python Snippet and run just that from a Python test script to convince yourself that there is nothing special about it being run from there.  Also, try adding in `print` statements to make sure that every variable is set to what you think it is.  Another quick thought is "Does this work if you change folder names to something NOT starting with a number?

Comment: I Tried everything including naming folders to just words, I am running it as a stand alone script, I wonder if that's the reason for the error.

Comment: What happens when you use the Upgrade Geodatabase tool to perform the upgrade on this file geodatabase (i.e. the first one in your listed workspaces) outside of ArcPy?

Comment: If I do the upgrade manually in Arc-catalog(by right clicking and going to properties), it throws up no error.

Comment: What about using the [**Upgrade Geodatabase**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000q7000000) tool?  I keep emphasising this because that is exactly what gets used by ArcPy and makes it available to Copy As Python Snippet.

Comment: @PolyGeo, it fails at this tool also I donot know why, spits out the same error

Comment: Can you revise your question so that it is about why the tool gives the error by deleting all the code from your Question and showing the tool dialog parameters and what shows up in the window when it is run, please?  Once the tool works for you so will the code.

Comment: Typically any time I get the ERROR 999999 it seems to be from lock issues. I close out of everything and run the python stand alone and it works. Is there anything opening the databases first?